# Date Picker Disabled Specific Date and Future date

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

How will I disable specific date together with future date? I tried this code but only the specific date is working.

```
var array = ["2017-10-07","2017-10-08"]

$('#INVOICE_TRANSACTIONDATE').datepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
        var string = jQuery.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
        return [ array.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
            maxDate: 0

    }

});
```

Comment: help pleaase........

Comment: yes also speciffic dates